# How can I use conditional formatting to check if a number repeats consecutively in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It's pretty much as simple as that—I'm uninterested in repeats that are non-consecutive. If I have the following sample data, 20 should be highlighted, but not 25 nor 27.

```
18
25
32
20
20
27
22
27
23
25
26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=(COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1)*((A1=A2))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent! This works. Is there any way to highlight both rows?

Comment: @clucko87 add one more rule with same formula just offset it by one row: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGdOT.png

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

An alternative solution that produces slightly different results to the one player0 suggested. This solution highlights all duplicates that are next to each other, rather than only the first. Apply conditional formatting to the full row (column A is assumed in this example), then use `Custom formula is` and the following formula

```
=OR(A1=A2,IF(ROW(A1)<>1,A1=OFFSET(A1,-1,)))*NOT(ISBLANK(A1))
```

[image]

### Explanation

Relative references are used throughout the formula, so as Google Sheets progresses down the column, each reference is updated by being moved the same number of rows down as well. In other words, the formula is always being used relative to the current cell that the conditional formatting rule is evaluating.

The `IF` function is used because when evaluating the top row, `OFFSET` cannot be used, so there is a special case for that situation. The `OR` checks whether the current cell is equal to either of its neighbours. `OFFSET` is used because `A0` is not a valid cell reference. I have assumed blank cells should not be marked as duplicates, so `ISBLANK` is used to check for that eventuality.

If you would like to check for duplicated blank cells as well, use this instead, removing the `NOT(ISBLANK(A1))` at the end.

```
=IF(ROW(A1)=1,A1=A2,OR(A1=A2,A1=OFFSET(A1,-1,)))
```

If you have a header row, you can simplify the formula using the following instead. If using this formula, only apply the conditional formatting rule to `A2:A` instead of `A:A`.

```
=OR(A2=A3,A2=A1)*NOT(ISBLANK(A2))
```

Functions used:

- [OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)
- [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)
- [NOT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en)
- [ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)

Comment: can you make it only highlight if say there are 4 in a streak consecutively in a column - this does it for every duplicate instance...