# How can I use conditional formatting to check if values repeat in a column non-consecutively

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A little similar to this question:
[How can I use conditional formatting to check if a number repeats consecutively in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73171911/how-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-to-check-if-a-number-repeats-consecutively)

But what I'm looking to do is to find if a value repeats more than once in a non-adjacent cell. So for example this is fine:
A
A
B
B
C
But this needs to be highlighted:
A
A
B
C
B <-- out of order

(they won't always be sorted like that, so alphabetically sorting options is not an option)

Couldn't find anything similar to this in other posts.

Comment: could you provide larger sample?

Comment: My sample isn't that big, it has about 10 cells altogether. I'm marking "mistakes" in red because sometimes users don't understand they need to obey certain rules in filling out the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find useful in A2:A (don't start in the first row but in the second) a formula like this in conditional formatting:

```
=AND(A2<>"",A2<>A1,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Works, thank you, marked as answered.